How to use agent-embedder-maven-plugin to add javaagent for tests in a spring-boot project
I have a spring-boot project where I want to enable loadTimeWeaving for entityManagerFactory.
I know that I can create a bean of InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver like below.
@Bean
public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
    return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
}

and it works well when I add --javaagent:<path-to-spring-instrument.jar>.
Command
java --javaagent:~/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/<version>/spring-instrument-<version>.jar -jar myjar.jar

There are two problems with the above approach-

I have to hardcode the version managed by spring-boot-starter-parent.
Adding javaagent at multiple deploy scripts as well as IDE config.

I came across agent-embedder-maven-plugin where I can embed javaagent as below.
<plugin>
    <groupId>dev.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>agent-embedder-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>embed-agent</id>
            <goals>
                 <goal>embed</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                 <javaAgents>
                      <agent>
                          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                          <artifactId>spring-instrument</artifactId>
                      </agent>
                  </javaAgents>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

But it doesn't work while running the tests and I have to manage two configs

Explicitly use javaagent for test
Use plugin for executing jar for deployment

How can I use agent-embedder-maven-plugin for running tests as well?
Currently, I am running test by adding configuration to surefire plugin like below -
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>
            --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
            -javaagent:${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/${spring-instrument.version}/spring-instrument-${spring-instrument.version}.jar
        </argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Edit -
Additionally, At time test code do not enable weaving, causing tests to fail.
I have added a GitHub repo (link), and pull request (link) that is causing issues for further help.

Back here, I not only advised you to ask a new question, but also to provide an MCVE on GitHub, which you have not done. I.e., I can only answer generically, because your question is generic. Garbage in, garbage out.

Apologies @kriegaex, It took a while to isolate the reproducer as these issues were happening in a large project. Could you please take a look at the Github Repo / PR?

There are some hard to understand things in your reproducer for me, I am going to reach out on GitHub, because here is not the right place to discuss.

Update after inspecting the reproducer project
I found out that the problem was neither AspectJ Maven Plugin nor AspectJ itself. Weaving works nicely. Instead, EclipseLink (EL) applies some additional byte code transformation on random helper methods in tests, if they happen to be returning entity types. A workaround is to factor those methods out into inner classes to make EL ignore them. This probably needs to be fixed in EL.
Fore more details, see my comment in this PR and the corresponding commit fixing the problem.

Original answer
I think, for regular tests your Surefire configuration with -javaagent is fine. By the way, --add-opens should no longer be necessary with the more recent AspectJ versions. Update: True, --add-opens is not needed for AspectJ, but the spring-core:5.3.18 version used in the sample project needs it. Probably, this is no longer necessary in more recent Spring versions.
If you want to test with the packaged artifact, this is to be considered an integration test. Use Failsafe for that, not Surefire. It runs in the verify phase, i.e., after package, and you can use the packaged artifact in your tests.
